# Ripple Effect gone after adding TapGestureRecognizer to ViewCell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added a custom `LongPressGestureRecognizer` to the ViewCell's root layout to handle certain cases, but after adding it, I find that the ripple effect when tapping the ViewCell is gone on Android. I tried to add back the animation by getting the native view, set background drawable to `Android.Resource.Attribute.SelectableItemBackground` by using below code

```
            int[] attrs = { Android.Resource.Attribute.SelectableItemBackground };

            var ta = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs);

            var drawable = ta.GetDrawable(0);
            nativeView.SetBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            ta.Recycle();
```

Even this doesn't work. Any other way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to know, I discarded the custom long press gesture recognizer way of achieving the goal, since it's the wrong way of doing things. On Android, we should use `ItemLongClick` event instead. Here is what I did, first, find out the native `ListView` through some method, my way is to first get the renderer of the `ListView`, then get underlying `ListView`. Another way is to use below code to find the `ListView`, but this way requires more work if you have multiple `ListView`

```
public static List<T> FindViews<T>(this ViewGroup viewGroup) where T : View
    {
        var result = new List<T>();

        var count = viewGroup.ChildCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);
            var item = child as T;
            if (item != null)
            {
                result.Add(item);
            }
            else if (child is ViewGroup)
            {
                var innerResult = FindViews<T>(child as ViewGroup);
                if (innerResult != null)
                {
                    result.AddRange(innerResult);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    var rootView =(ViewGroup)CurrentActivity.Window.DecorView.RootView
    var nativeListView = rootView.FindView<Android.Widget.ListView>();
```

Then override the `OnAppearing` method of the `Page`, in it, attach `ItemLongClick` event handler. Also override `OnDisappearing` method, in it, detach the `ItemLongClick` event handler. This is important. Simply add `ItemLongClick` event handler in constructor seems not working.